# Django Reverse for 'setrefresh' not found. 'setrefresh' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, function, view

I have a web page and on this webpage I have a button. I am trying to get it so that when the user clicks this button it will call an API endpoints and update the database model I have created.

Please let me know if you need more info, I'm completely lost at the moment.

**sets.html**

```
{% block content %}
  <div class="background card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <button class="btn" id="setRefresh" style="border: 1px solid #555555; color: #555555" onclick="location.href={% url 'setrefresh' %}"><i class="fas fa-sync"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock%}
```

**views.py**

```
def sets(request):
    return render(request,
                  "main/sets.html",
                  {"Sets": Set.objects.all})


def setrefresh(request):
    try:
        response = requests.request("GET", "https://api.scryfall.com/sets")
        data = response.json()
        data = data["data"]
        for entry in data:
            s = Set()
            s.scry_id = entry["id"]
            s.code = entry["code"]
            s.name = entry["name"]
            s.set_type = entry["set_type"]
            s.release_date = entry["released_at"]
            s.card_count = entry["card_count"]
            s.digital_only = entry["digital"]
            s.foil_only = entry["foil_only"]
            s.nonfoil_only = entry["nonfoil_only"]
            s.icon = entry["icon_svg_uri"]
            s.status = 0
            s.save()
        return HttpResponse("ok")
    except Exception:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.dashboard, name="dashboard"),
    path('sets', views.sets, name="sets"),
    path('cards', views.cards, name="cards"),

    url(r'^setrefresh/', views.setrefresh, name='setrefresh'),
]
```

**Directory Tree**

[image]

Comment: Can you share you directly tree?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add **app_name** to **urls.py**

```
app_name = 'your_app_name'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.dashboard, name="dashboard"),
    path('sets', views.sets, name="sets"),
    path('cards', views.cards, name="cards"),

    url(r'^setrefresh/', views.setrefresh, name='setrefresh'),
]
```

2. Mention in Html

```
{% block content %}
  <div class="background card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <button class="btn" id="setRefresh" style="border: 1px solid #555555; color: #555555" onclick="location.href={% url 'your_app_name:setrefresh' %}"><i class="fas fa-sync"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock%}
```